# Oracle Invalid Number error with NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have a `varchar2` column that I need to convert to `number`

The format is as follows:

```
+000000000000030203.38
```

Database level: NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,

Session Level: NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ,.

I have tried:

```
select to_number('+000000000000030203.38','S999999999999999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') from MYTAB t
```

But it throws `invalid number` error.

What are the correct parameters of `to_number` function here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is the decimal separator, the second is the thousands separator.

Your supplied NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS takes precedence, so you're saying that numbers will be expressed with comma as the decimal separator and comma as the thousands separator.

Use the 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''' instead.